# how to set vertical alingn of a div shown as circle?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

this is what i created:

[image]

This is what i want like:

[image]

this is my code:

```
<div id="OR"><span style=" vertical-align: middle;background:blue;">OR</span></div>
```

this is css:

```
div #OR { border-radius:50%;border-style:1px solid black;background:red;width:42px;height:42px;float:right; background:red;vertical-align: middle;}
div #OR span{ vertical-align: middle; }
```

so please help me to bring thart OR in a center of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will need an extra element for the *OR* text, what you need is the `line-height` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhC2L/)

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px; /* Equals elements height */
    text-align: center;
}
```

This solution is perfect if you want to `vertical-align` single word, if you want to perfectly center an element horizontally and vertically, other two approaches are to use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` or use CSS Positioning.

---

CSS Positioning way..

Explanation: Here am using `position: relative;` on the wrapper/parent element and than am assigning `position: absolute;` for the child element. Though, here's a catch, you need to assign fixed width to the child element you are trying to center.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhC2L/1/)

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-top: -10px; /* Half of the elements height */
    margin-left: -12px; /* Half of the elements width */
}
```